# Writing in Java to a byte[] array that is allocated in C++

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have some memory that needs to be allocated in C++ and written in Java using an interface which takes byte[] without extra copying. I can't change the Java interface. I saw DirectByteBuffer which I can create in C++ via NewDirectByteBuffer however my research shows that array() isn't implemented.

Is there a way to do what I want without extra copies? Thank you.

Comment: No. `byte[]` is a reference, and references are managed by the JVM. It can change its place in memory at any time.

Comment: Your best bet would be [`GetByteArrayElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#getprimitivetypearrayelements-routines). This method may or may not copy the array.

Comment: *Is there a way to do what I want without extra copies?*  Don't worry about any extra copies until you have demonstrable performance problems with your program **and** actually doing the work to profile the performance of your program indicates that extra copies are the cause.  And even then you don't fix the extra copies until you've verified your underlying algorithm isn't the root cause of the performance problem - for example, bad design turned an O(n) problem into an O(n^3) problem.